# How to get the column name of the primary key through jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

I have the code as follows:

```
DatabaseMetaData dmd = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = dmd.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, tableName);

while(rs.next()){
    primaryKey = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
}
```

rs is not null while `rs.next()` always return `false`, anyone has idea about it? Thanks.

Comment: Which DB engine are you using? As not all drivers / DB engines might support to read the medatada from jdbc.

Comment: Normally we use **ResultSetMetaData**(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) for this. I could not find any suitable method for your requirement though.

Comment: @ManuPK In this case `DatabaseMetaData` is the right class.

Comment: Are you sure you spelled the tablename correctly (upper vs. LOWER case?) And does the table actually have a **primary key** (not just a unique key?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. metadata interface implementation was implemented by driver vendors. It may not be supported by some driver and some db.
   Here is text from javadoc:
   Some DatabaseMetaData methods return lists of information in the form of ResultSet objects. Regular ResultSet methods, such as getString and getInt, can be used to retrieve the data from these ResultSet objects. If a given form of metadata is not available, an empty ResultSet will be returned.
2. table name is case sensitive in oracle
3. or try the below approach

   ```
   DatabaseMetaData dm = conn.getMetaData( );
   ResultSet rs = dm.getExportedKeys( "" , "" , "table1" );
   while( rs.next( ) ) 
   {    
     String pkey = rs.getString("PKCOLUMN_NAME");
     System.out.println("primary key = " + pkey);
   }
   ```

   you can also use getCrossReference or getImportedKeys to retrieve primary key

Comment: Is there a way to get the type of the primary keys as well?

Comment: **@Zaheer** did you manage to figure out how to get the `type` of *primary key*?

Comment: **@Zaheer**, I believe [this](https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/jdbc/recipes/ResultSet-ColumnType.shtml) would work but there must be an easier way