# I need to get the primary key columns name for oracle database table

Tags: java, oracle

I need to get the primary key columns name for oracle database table but using below code i am getting no primary column.Though my table is having primary key with combination of 2 columns

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "JB_ODS", "pwd");
DatabaseMetaData dbmd = con.getMetaData();
List < String > tablePrimaryKeys = new ArrayList < String > ();
ResultSet p_Keys = dbmd.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, tableName);
while (p_Keys.next()) {
    system.out.println(p_Keys.getString(4));
}
```

Here i have 2 primary keys for my table but this resultset is not having any primary key. It is not going inside while loop

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/GetPrimaryKeyColumnFromATable.htm) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506884/how-to-get-the-column-name-of-the-primary-key-through-jdbc)

Comment: I have gone through that link and i am also following the same approach but the problem is i am getting empty resultset for primary keys.

Comment: Had the question been asked with your complete code snippet, others would have been able to help you. Hence I would suggest that you post your code snippet by editing the question.

Comment: Hi I am able to figure out the issue but it seems illogical as when i give table name in caps then it is fetching primary keys but when giving table name in small letters then its not working not able to make out why its behaving like this as database is not case sensitive.

Comment: Glad to know that you have managed to solve the issue. From the link which has been posted yesterday "The Oracle database stores its table names as Upper-Case,
    if you pass a table name in lowercase characters, it will not work."